# Help with OnTriggerEntered + Canvas UI

Tags: unity, c#

This seems like it should be incredibly easy and I know there are other posts out there with a similar title, but I promise you I have looked at all of them. All I want is for my canvas that simply says "you win" to appear when I enter an invisible box collider that I have . My canvas is by default set to disabled.

```
public class YouWin : MonoBehaviour {
public Canvas myCanvas;

private void Start()
{
    myCanvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();

}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collision Collider)
{
    {
        myCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

This script seems incredibly simple and straightforward, but for whatever reason, when I enter my box, nothing at all happens. Why might this be? What am I missing?

As per an answer I also tried

```
public class YouWin : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject canvas;

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider Collider)
{
    {
        canvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

But had no luck with this either. I've been tinkering to no avail, can you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Is this script on the object with the canvas?

Comment: the script is attached to the box that i collide with

Comment: Why are you adding redundant brackets though?

Comment: It is just leftover from trying other stuff. That isn't what's causing the problem though.

Comment: Have you checked the collider table to see whether your collider systems are compatible? It could be the case that you're just combine the wrong collider types.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what exactly is wrong, here are a few things can could be wrong:

- Since you are using `OnTriggerEnter()` make sure the object attached to this script, has a `Collider` set with `isTrigger` to `true`.
- I'm not sure why you would attach a `Canvas` to an object that seems to resemble an actual object (either 2D or 3D). Try making the object with the `Canvas` a separate object, linked with `public Canvas canvas;` (also suggested by another answer). The idea of the `Canvas` is that it draws its children, so there (usually) isn't a need to make an object both draw stuff on the screen **and** being a `Canvas`.
- Maybe `OnTriggerEnter()` activates as expected, but you just don't see anything because you only enable a `Canvas` element in it, which could theoretically draw nothing on top of the screen (depending how you set it up). Try replacing `myCanvas.gameObject.setActive(true);` with something like `Debug.Log("canvas enables itself now");`, when running the game, take a look in the console to see if this runs or not.
- Also make sure that at least one of your objects has a `RigidBody` attached (Thanks @DMGregory), otherwise collisions are not triggered. You can take a look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) for a table explaining how Unity calculates collisions and triggers.

It might also be useful to share your hierarchy, I suspect there's something there that could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the `GetComponent` call I think. GetComponent only works when the thing you're getting is on the same game object as the script.

Instead of getting the canvas game object that way, make a public game object variable for the canvas and then drag and drop your canvas into that slot in the inspector.

Just like this:

```
public class YouWin : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject canvas;

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider Collider)
{
    canvas.SetActive(true);
}
```

All you have to do now is drag the canvas object into the slot that opens up in the inspector.

Comment: It's still just not happening. I have exactly what you put. I also tried void OnTriggerEnter (Collider Collider) but that didn't work either. This script should be attached with the box collider right?

Comment: The reason I changed it to (Collider Collider) is because unity was telling me I had to.

Comment: Yeah I think Collider is correct actually, sorry about that, I just didn't even see that when I copy and pasted your code. Good practice is also to use camel case (lower case to start) for your argument name. Did you make sure to drag and drop the canvas game object into the slot in the inspector?

Comment: I put the canvas object into the slot in the inspector, yes.

Comment: Is the box game object active? Is isTrigger checked?

Comment: They sure are.. This is depressing

Comment: [Works fine here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tb5tvUhTafp78PXoFSPWm-NgUdya9_WF) . Make there is a rigid body.

In play mode drag the player cube into the other cube.